# Criar uma tableView com 616 itens

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tenho que criar uma tabela com 616 itens, cada item possuem 5 detalhes.

Exemplo:

item 1 - Aspirina
Risco: Medio
Lactacao: Alto
Gravide: Baixo

item 2 - Dipirona
Risco: Medio
Lactacao: Alto
Gravide: Baixo
...

Na tabela irá aparecer somente o nome do item (Aspirina, Dipirona, ...)
Quando clicado no item da tabela, abre uma `detailviewcontroller` para mostrar o conteúdo restante.

Qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?
Se fossem poucos itens ate que eu faria isso na mão mesmo, criando instância de objeto, mas com 616, como faço?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vou descrever aqui uma solução que adota a seguinte arquitetura:

- Os dados são locais ao dispositivo, inicialmente armazenados em memória não-volátil e estão em formato [*property list*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list);
- Os dados são carregados da memória não-volátil e armazenados em dicionários na memória. Todos os dados são lidos para a memória de uma só vez e não defini uma classe `Medicamento` específica;
- As gradações de risco dos medicamentos são armazenadas como strings

O primeiro passo é criar um arquivo .plist contendo todos os dados a serem apresentados. No menu principal, escolha File > New > File… e então, dentro da categoria iOS, Resource > Property List. Neste exemplo, dei-lhe o nome Medicamentos.plist. Você pode então preencher os dados manualmente. Para esta resposta, eu defini o arquivo como contendo um dicionário com chave “medicamentos”, que, por sua vez, é um vetor contendo uma lista de medicamentos. Cada medicamento individual é um dicionário contendo chaves “nome”, “risco”, “lactacao” e “gravidez”. O arquivo poderia começar diretamente como um vetor, mas ter um dicionário facilita a inclusão de outros dados no futuro sem que seja necessário alterar código que se baseia nos dados antigos.

[image: Dados no formato plist]

Se você <kbd>⌃</kbd>-clicar o arquivo no navegador de projetos, você pode escolher a opção Open As > Source Code: o Xcode irá exibir-lhe os mesmos dados, desta vez em formato XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>medicamentos</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>nome</key>
            <string>Aspirina</string>
            <key>risco</key>
            <string>Médio</string>
            <key>lactacao</key>
            <string>Alto</string>
            <key>gravidez</key>
            <string>Baixo</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>nome</key>
            <string>Dipirona</string>
            <key>risco</key>
            <string>Médio</string>
            <key>lactacao</key>
            <string>Alto</string>
            <key>gravidez</key>
            <string>Baixo</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Se esses dados vêm de um banco de dados, você pode escrever um script que os formata da forma acima para evitar ter que digitá-los. Além disso, talvez seja mais fácil editar como XML do que visualmente.

Em seguida, você terá uma representação externa dos dados que fará parte do *app bundle* gerado pelo Xcode e instalado nos dispositivos.

No *view controller* mestre, você precisa carregar os dados e armazená-los. Neste exemplo, estou armazenando-os em uma variável de instância chamada `_medicamentos`:

```
@interface BAVMasterViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *medicamentos;
@end
```

No método `-viewDidLoad`, escreva o seguinte:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Medicamentos" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];
    self.medicamentos = plist[@"medicamentos"];
}
```

O primeiro passo é obter a URL que descreve o local onde está armazenado o arquivo Medicamentos.plist dentro do *app bundle*. Feito isso, o método `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:]` lê os dados no formato plist e cria um dicionário (lembre-se de que definimos que o arquivo .plist é um dicionário) com base no arquivo. O dicionário contém uma única chave chamada “medicamentos”, cujo valor é um vetor contendo uma lista de medicamentos. Armazenamos esse vetor na propriedade `medicamentos`.

Feito isso, basta usar o vetor como os dados do *view controller* mestre. Cada elemento desse vetor é um dicionário contendo “nome”, “risco”, “lactacao” e “gravidez”. No mestre, exibimos o nome do medicamento:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *medicamento = self.medicamentos[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = medicamento[@"nome"];
    return cell;
}
```

Resultando em:

[image: Exemplo do view controller mestre]

Quando o usuário toca um medicamento, seguimos para o *view controller* detalhe, passando o medicamento escolhido pelo usuário:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *medicamento = self.medicamentos[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setMedicamento:medicamento];
    }
}
```

Note que o *view controller* detalhe recebe `-setMedicamento:` para saber qual medicamento exibir. Além disso, contém *labels* para cada dado exibido:

```
@interface BAVDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *medicamento;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *riscoGeralLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *riscoLactacaoLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *riscoGravidezLabel;
@end
```

Ao receber um medicamento, ele é armazenado e a *view* é configurada:

```
- (void)setMedicamento:(NSDictionary *)medicamento
{
    if (medicamento != _medicamento) {
        _medicamento = medicamento;
        [self configureView];
    }
}
```

E, na configuração da *view*, os dados do medicamento são enviados para os *labels* e o título do detalhe recebe o nome do medicamento:

```
- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.medicamento) {
        self.title = self.medicamento[@"nome"];
        self.riscoGeralLabel.text = self.medicamento[@"risco"];
        self.riscoLactacaoLabel.text = self.medicamento[@"lactacao"];
        self.riscoGravidezLabel.text = self.medicamento[@"gravidez"];
    }
}
```

Resultando em:

[image: Exemplo do view controller detalhe]

Esta é uma solução simples. Algumas alternativas para a arquitetura da solução:

- Obter os dados de servidores Web, quiçá com cache local no aplicativo;
- Usar outro formato de serialização. JSON é popular em serviços Web e nada impede que seja usado localmente. Se os dados forem muitos e tê-los todos em memória (como ocorre com plist e JSON) não é viável, você pode usar Core Data ou SQLite. Da forma como você apresentou — 616 medicamentos —, não precisa preocupar-se com memória;
- Em vez de usar strings literais para as chaves do dicionário, usar constantes. Isto evita erros de digitação e torna mais fácil alterar chaves se e quando necessário;
- Em vez de usar dicionários para armazenar os dados dentro do processo, convertê-los de dicionários para instâncias de uma classe modelo, e.g. `Medicamento`, que contém propriedades para cada dado. Desta forma, fica mais claro que dados estão disponíveis e quais os respectivos tipos. O [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) é um framework do GitHub que pode ajudá-lo na manutenção desse tipo de classes modelos;
- Em vez de armazenar as gradações de risco como strings, você pode armazená-las como números (e.g. 1 para Baixo, 2 para Médio e 3 para Alto) e convertê-los para strings apenas ao apresentar os dados. Isto irá reduzir a memória usada pelo processo dado que números são representados mais compactamente do que strings.

Comment: Ola, nao chamaria isso de resposta de um ótimo tutorial, agora deixa eu lhe perguntar, e se eu precisar de adicionar um Search com o NSPredicate para filtrar com os nomes dos medicamentos como funcionaria isso para eu nao perder a referencia na detailviewcontroler, Muito Obrigado

Comment: Perfeito, me ajudou muito ! Eu precisava fazer um exemplo de diretório, com tableview e comecei a partir do seu exemplo. Muito obrigado