# Filtrando conteudo de TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tenho uma Property List, com a seguinte estrutura com um total de 616 registros. (Aspirina e Dipirona são exemplos)

[image: propertyList]

Estou precisando inserir somente o nome do produto em uma tabela e ter a opção de filtrar com o (Search Bar and Search Display Controller), depois do filtro realizado pelo usuário ele poderá clicar em algum produto que sera enviado a uma nova *view* com o conteúdo restante de cada Produtos ex: (Risco, Lactacao, Gravidez)

Comment: Conforme comentei em [outra pergunta sua](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15578/criando-um-array-com-as-chaves-de-um-dictionary), você tem certeza de que `medicamentos` deve ser um dicionário em vez de vetor? Da forma como você modelou, não há como descobrir o nome de um medicamento individual.

Comment: Nao precisa ser necessariamente Dicionario, se me informar outra forma de eu conseguir oq preciso, show de bola!

Comment: Sinceramente eu nao estou querendo fazer com BD, como é um conteudo fixo, se desse para eu fazer com PropertyList, seria muito bom, obrigado pela atencao @Bavarious

Comment: Nao sei se existe funcoes para isso, mas se eu fizer o nome dos produtos em Vetor, como eu vou resgatar os seus respectivos conteudos na proxima View (quando ele tocar no produto) (Risco, Gravidez e Lactacao), esse foi o motivo de fazer um Dictionary, pois o produto fica como chave para o seu conteudo, nao sei se o meu pensamento está correto, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou descrever uma solução que se baseia na arquitetura descrita [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15285/7835), a qual já contém uma tabela mestre e uma *view* detalhe para mostrar medicamentos. Em particular, medicamentos é um vetor contendo dicionários onde cada dicionário representa um medicamento. Além disso, o dicionário do medicamento contém uma chave “nome”.

O primeiro passo é editar sua *storyboard* e arrastar um objeto *Search Bar and Search Display Controller* para a *view* mestre conforme a figura abaixo.

[image: Search Bar and Search Display Controller]

Isto atrelará um *search display controller* ao *controller* mestre e apresentará a barra de pesquisa. O *search display controller* apresenta os dados filtrados em uma tabela, então você pode reutilizar os métodos de fonte de dados do *controller*, tendo o cuidado de discernir quando mostrar todos os dados ou apenas os dados filtrados.

Comecemos pela extensão da classe mestre, que irá seguir os protocolos `UISearchBarDelegate` e `UISearchDisplayDelegate`. Além disso, a classe armazena, além do vetor com todos os dados, um segundo vetor com os dados filtrados:

```
@interface BAVMasterViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *medicamentos;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *medicamentosFiltrados;
@end
```

Para a filtragem, vamos definir um método que recebe o critério de busca, filtra o vetor `medicamentos` com base nesse critério e armazena o resultado no vetor `medicamentosFiltrados`:

```
- (void)filtrarMedicamentosComTexto:(NSString *)texto escopo:(NSString *)escopo
{
    NSPredicate *predicado = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.nome contains[cd] %@", texto];
    self.medicamentosFiltrados = [self.medicamentos filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicado];
}
```

Note que o predicado faz uso do atributo nome, que está armazenado em cada dicionário representando um medicamento. O `[cd]` indica que o `contains` deve ignorar tanto caixa (maiúsculas ou minúsculas) quanto diacríticos (acentos). O escopo é ignorado.

Esse método é usado nos métodos do protocolo `UISearchDisplayDelegate` que perguntam se os dados devem ser recarregados quando o usuário troca o critério de busca:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSString *escopo = [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]];
    [self filtrarMedicamentosComTexto:searchString escopo:escopo];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    NSString *escopo = [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption];
    [self filtrarMedicamentosComTexto:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text escopo:escopo];
    return YES;
}
```

Ambos os métodos devolvem `YES`, indicando que o *search display controller* precisa recarregar seus dados.

Resta agora prover os dados para o *search display controller*. Como o mestre serve tanto dados não filtrados (a tabela mestre) quando filtrados (a tabela do *search display controller*), alteramos os métodos do mestre para que ele decida se deve usar dados filtrados ou não:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *medicamentos = (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView ? self.medicamentosFiltrados : self.medicamentos);
    return medicamentos.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *medicamentos = (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView ? self.medicamentosFiltrados : self.medicamentos);
    NSDictionary *medicamento = medicamentos[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = medicamento[@"nome"];
    return cell;
}
```

Note que os dois métodos acima verificam se a tabela que está solicitando dados é a tabela do _search display controller. Caso seja, esses métodos usam o vetor `medicamentosFiltrados`; caso contrário, usam o vetor `medicamentos`.

Falta apenas o método `-prepareForSegue:sender:`, responsável por configurar o detalhe:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSArray *medicamentos = (self.searchDisplayController.active ? self.medicamentosFiltrados : self.medicamentos);
        NSDictionary *medicamento = medicamentos[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setMedicamento:medicamento];
    }
}
```

Ao contrário dos dois outros métodos acima, o `-prepareForSegue:sender:` não recebe um parâmetro `UITableView *`, então nós verificamos se o *search display controller* está ativo, i.e., visível. Caso esteja, o usuário tocou um medicamento na tabela de resultados da busca, então obtemos o medicamento do vetor `medicamentosFiltrados`; caso contrário, usamos o vetor `medicamentos`.

Nenhuma alteração é necessária no *controller* detalhe. Lembre-se de que ele recebe um medicamento sob a forma de um dicionário e esse dicionário contém todos os dados do medicamento.

---

**medicamentos: vetor ou dicionário?**

De forma geral, um dicionário representa um objeto e um vetor representa uma coleção (sequencial) de objetos. Uma lista de medicamentos é uma coleção de medicamentos, ou seja, um vetor de dicionários onde cada dicionário é um medicamento individual.

No caso específico da exibição de medicamentos em uma `UITableView`, tabelas, por definição, são posicionais: há uma quantidade de linhas na tabela e cada linha tem um número entre 0 e o total de linhas menos um. Um vetor funciona exatamente da mesma forma, então o mapeamento de elemento do vetor para linha da tabela é direto.

Se fôssemos escrever uma solução em que medicamentos fosse um dicionário conforme descrito na pergunta, precisaríamos implementar um mapeamento dos pares chave-valor do dicionário para a tabela. Dado que a tabela funciona com posições (e.g. `indexPath.row`), este mapeamento precisa atrelar uma posição numérica a cada par chave-valor do dicionário. Uma alternativa é obter a lista de chaves do dicionário com `-[NSDicionary allKeys]`, que devolve… um vetor. No fim das contas, acabamos por usar vetor novamente.

Além disso, veja que, da forma como projetado na pergunta, o nome do medicamento serve como chave, e o valor associado a essa chave é um dicionário contendo os riscos apenas, sem o nome. Isto significa que, com esse dicionário sozinho, não é possível saber o nome do medicamento: é necessário buscá-lo dentro do dicionário pai ou é necessário repassar o nome do medicamento junto com o dicionário.