# Criando um Array com as Chaves de um Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

tenho um dictionary conforme imagem abaixo e gostaria de jogar os nomes das chaves do dictionary medicamentos para um array, como consigo realizar tao funcao

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que `medicamentos` é um dicionário em vez de um vetor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDictionary possui o método `- (NSArray *)allKeys` que retorna um array contendo todas as chaves do dicionário

Comment: É bom lembrar que a ordem das chaves no vetor devolvido por `-[NSDictionary allKeys]` é indefinida. Em particular, não há garantia de que a ordem seja igual em execuções distintas mesmo que o dicionário contenha os mesmos pares chave-valor.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * path= [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Medicamentos" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSDictionary * dadosArquivo =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSArray * medicamentos =[dadosArquivo objectForKey:@"medicamentos"]; //

   NSLog(@"%@", medicamentos);
```

acho que e isso.